# Gravatar Error: Please specify a valid email address

Tags: laravel, gravatar

I am trying to use a gravatar in my application.

I have a collection of employees. Not all have a photo, therefore I check if the avatar_type === gravatar in order pass a valid URL of the email if exist therefore I do a loop:

```
foreach ($employees as $employee) {
  if($employee->avatar_type === 'gravatar') { 
      $employee->avatar_location = gravatar()->get($employee->email, ['size'=>80]);
   }
}
```

The first Item of the collection thet does not have a photo and needs a gravatar looks like this:

```
App\Models\Employee\Employee {#2898 ▼
      ...
      #attributes: array:14 [▼
        "firstname" => "Mary"
        "lastname" => "Brown"
        "email" => "mariabrown@yahoo.com"
        "avatar_location" => null
        "avatar_type" => "gravatar" // <- Here is the flag
      ]
```

However, even if the email is valid ("email" => "mariabrown@yahoo.com") I get the following error:

**Creativeorange\Gravatar\Exceptions\InvalidEmailException 

Please specify a valid email address**

I even made a test and "dd" the email inside the loop and the email is there. Like this:

```
foreach ($employees as $employee) { 

 dd($employee->email)  //<- The email is here

  if($employee->avatar_type === 'gravatar') { 
      $employee->avatar_location = gravatar()->get($employee->email, ['size'=>80]);
   }
}
```

What am I missing here. Why is not a valid email?

I am using Laravel 6.13

The gravatar package is downloaded, installed and working in other places of the app (in the user profile page).

Comment: `dd($employee->email)` this will stop on first employee/iteration. May be some other user's email id is invalid

Comment: @Sehdev, yes a dd() stops the  loop. It was a test. I have gone through the list of employees (there is just 10, tihs is a test) in the database and all emails are valid formatted

Comment: @Sehdev: I found the problem: There was a empty space in front of one email. I just arr a trim to the email address: trim($employee->email). Thanks for getting it to my attention

Comment: Welcome. Keep learning!

Answer (score 0):

You need to sanitize all the inputs before proceeding. In laravel we can write a simple middleware which performs this task on the fly. Here is an article which explains clearly. [check this medium article](https://medium.com/@melihovv/how-to-sanitize-input-data-in-declarative-manner-in-laravel-e4486068f751)
Hope this helps.